# Python "in" operator not finding substring

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to find if any substring in a list of substrings is in a given string. To do so, I loop over the items of the list and check if they exist in the string using python's `in` operator. I am getting `False` values even though I am sure one of the substring exists in the string. I have tried stripping all whitespace and using the `.lower()` method on both the titles (substrings) and the text I am matching them to and I still get `False` values throughout.

My code:

```
example = "Research Policy journal homepage: www.elsevier.com/locate/respol Editorial Introduction to special section on university–industry linkages: The signiﬁcance of tacit knowledge and the role of intermediaries The papers in this special section of research World Bank study on the growth prospects of the leading East Asian economies."

list_of_titles = ["Introduction to special section on university–industry linkages: The significance of tacit knowledge and the role of intermediaries", "another title", "another title"]

for title in list_of_titles:
   if title in example:
       print("Yes")
   else:
       print("No")
```

I get "No"s for all titles in the list.

Comment: The second i of "signiﬁcance" is not the same between your example and your list_of_titles.

Comment: It looks like you have a special character in "significance" in example. Rather than an "f" and "i", it is a single character.

Comment: @nofinator yes I see what you mean now. Is there a way I can deal with this? thanks.

Comment: @Drakax is there a way I can deal with this in python? thanks.

Comment: @Drakax Actually the _second_ i is the same  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried stripping all whitespace and using the .lower() method on both the titles ...

Instead of `.lower()`, you could use [casefolding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) which normalize the ligatures "ﬁ" into "fi".

```
>>> "signiﬁcance".casefold() == "significance"
True
```

If you want something similar, which is still keeping case-sensitivity, consider [unidecode](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode):

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode("Signiﬁcance")
'Significance'
```